# Using SharedPreferences inside MyXMLHandlerTemp

Tags: java, android

I have a class named **MyXMLHandlerTemp** which **extends DefaultHandler**. The class is used for parsing data.

I want to use **SharedPreferences** inside MyXMLHandlerTemp  class but it gives me error saying

> getSharedPreferences(String,int) is undefined for the type MyXMLHandlerTemp

Is it possible to use SharedPreferences inside MyXMLHandlerTemp? If not then what can be alternative solution?

Comment: pls format code as `code`, not as bold!

Comment: I am new here , That's why don't know lots of things like how code , normal text and other stuffs should be presented. Anyways in future , i will try to make things present properly. @ Drakosha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass context from calling activity to the MyXmlHandlerTemp constructor . So using that context you can use sharedPreference in  MyXmlHandlerTemp class.

```
private Context context;
MyXMLHandlerTemp(Context context)
{
      this.context = context;
}

context.getSharedPreferences(String,int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Chirag's solution, you could pass the `Preference` instance obtained in `Activity`/`Application'` or another context by `getSharedPreferences` as a parameter to your xml handler.
**Added**
the code in your activity that calls xml handler:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("yourPreferenceFileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
MyXMLHandlerTemp = new MyXMLHandlerTemp(prefs);
```

Constructor in `MyXMLHandlerTemp`:

```
public MyXMLHandlerTemp(SharedPreferences prefs){
   this.prefs = prefs;
}
```

This requires you to add private field `prefs` of type `SharedPreferences` ti your handler class. Then instead of calling `getSharedPreferences` inside your handler, use this field `prefs`:

```
prefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
```

and so on.

Comment: Please give some more details about your solution , Thanks.

Comment: Okey i got it , the idea is clear to me now , Thanks for the alternate idea ... :)